# What is the Hebrew for Sons of Man (Prov 8:4)?

Tags: hebrew, proverbs

Proverbs 8:4 (ESV):

> To you, O **men**, I *call*,
> and my *cry* is to **the children of man.**

(KJV):

> Unto you, O **men**, I *call*; and *my voice* is to **the sons of man**.

(Can't find "Sons of Man" in my Strong's Condordance.)

What is the original Hebrew for Children of Man/Sons of man?
Is the terminology related to Genesis 6:4 "Daughters of Men"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two Hebrew words of Prov 8:4 are:

> בְּנֵ֥י אָדָֽם = sons of man/mankind

In Gen 6:4 we have

> בְּנֹ֣ות הָֽאָדָ֔ם = daughters of the man(kind)

"**Son of Man**" can mean either a human or a mortal person such as in the book of Ezekiel, eg, Eze 28:2 (many times).

"**Sons of God**" is either a phrase about mortal humans generally (John 1:13), or, saved people generally, such as Hos 1:10, 1 John 3:10, Rom 8:21, etc.

The real question is, on the basis of the book of 1 Enoch, what does Gen 6:4 - mortals or saved vs unsaved people?  That question has been debated in many places on this site and I will not debate it in this question.

Answer (score 1):

> אֲלֵיכֶ֣ם אִישִׁ֣ים אֶקְרָ֑א וְ֝קֹולִ֗י אֶל־**בְּנֵ֥י אָדָֽם**׃ (Proverbs
> 8:4, TR)

The "sons of men" is "בְּנֵ֥י אָדָֽם" (bə·nê ’ā·ḏām).  It could be translated as "sons of mankind" but that sounds more awkward, which is why some translations soften it by using "children" instead.  But the "bene" is literally "sons" in Hebrew.

See Strong's [H1121](http://www.blbclassic.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H1121&t=KJV) and [H120](http://www.blbclassic.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H120&t=KJV).

Answer (score 1):

Proverbs 8:4: sons of man -- בְּנֵ֥י אָדָֽם -- *bney 'adam*

Genesis 6:4: daughters of man -- בְּנֹ֣ות הָֽאָדָ֔ם -- *bnowt ha'adam*

Genesis 31:28: Laban did combine the two rather than use one term: לְבָנַ֖י וְלִבְנֹתָ֑י
This may have been drawing things out as a sign of anger, like using your full name.

Genesis 3:16: However, in many cases the plural of son, בֵּן (*ben*), means children, בָנִ֑ים (*banim*, absolute plural, בְּנֵ֥י [*bney*] construct plural, *sons of, children of*).  There are many examples of this.

Exodus 3:10 is another obvious one: בְנֵֽי־יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל
-- *bney yishra'el* -- children of Israel

Answer (score 0):

The Ivrit of Mishlei chapter 8 verse 4 states : אֲלֵיכֶ֣ם אִישִׁ֣ים אֶקְרָ֑א וְ֜קוֹלִ֗י אֶל־בְּנֵ֥י אָדָֽם | Alei-Kem, Ishim, Eqra. Ve-Qoli el-B'nei Adam.

In English, "Proverbs" chapter 8 verse 4 would read : "To-you, men, I-will-call. And-My-Voice [is] to-Sons [of] Man."